# p5.js classes (class "example" is not changing my this.x value)

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, p5.js

I want to move an ellipse but I am stuck because my this.x value isn't changing... print("hit this.y = 30"); is working just fine but this--; is not working. Is anything blocking it? Thank you in advance for your time!

```
let redBubble = 0;
let x = false;
let y = 0;
let d = 0;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    redBubble = new Bubble(300, 100, 10);
}

function draw() {
    background(56, 23, 56);
        redBubble.show();
        redBubble.toRight();
        redBubble.toLeft();
        redBubble.example();
};

class Bubble {
    constructor(x, y, d) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.d = d;
    }
    show() {
        fill(255);
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.d * 2);
    }
    toRight() {
        if (this.x < 350) {
            this.x = this.x + 1;
        } else if (this.x === 350) {
            this.y = this.y - 1;
        }
    }
    toLeft() {
        if (this.y <= 30) {
            x = true;
        } else if (this.y === 30) {
            x = false;
        }
    }
    example() {
        if (x) {
            this.x--; // not working
            print("hit this.y = 30"); // working
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running, but it sounds like it's not doing what you want it to.

All of your functions `show()`, `toRight()`, `toLeft()`, `example()`, are running every single draw. So every single time, `toRight()` is incrementing `this.x` by 1 (unless `this.x` is exactly 350). So when `example()` decrements it by 1, they are in effect canceling each other out and not changing `this.x`, when `x` is true and `this.x` is 349.

If you wanted the net effect to be `this.x` to decrease, you could replace `this.x--;` with `this.x = this.x - 2;`. But this is not a great solution.

#### Using states

It looks like you want to do different things at different stages of your animation, i.e. go right, then go up, then go left. As you've discovered, it can be pretty tricky to coordinate all of these different changes when all of your functions are running every cycle.

Instead, it's a lot easier to conditionally run only the functions you want, depending on what stage of your animation you're in. For this you can use an internal variable to store what it should be doing (I'll use `this.direction` for this example). Then in your draw function, you'd use `if`/`then` statements, like this:

```
function draw() {
    background(56, 23, 56);
    redBubble.show();
    if (redBubble.direction === 'right') {
         redBubble.goRight();
    } else if (redBubble.direction === 'up') {
         redBubble.goUp();
    } else if (redBubble.direction === 'left') {
         redBubble.goLeft();
    }
};
```

And then in your individual functions, you'd change direction based on some condition. For example:

```
toRight() {
    this.x = this.x + 1;
    if (this.x === 350) {
        this.direction = 'up';
    }
}
```

Here's a working snippet of the above technique:

```js
let redBubble;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    redBubble = new Bubble(300, 100, 10);
}

function draw() {
    background(56, 23, 56);
    redBubble.show();
    if (redBubble.direction === 'right') {
        redBubble.goRight();
    } else if (redBubble.direction === 'up') {
        redBubble.goUp();
    } else if (redBubble.direction === 'left') {
        redBubble.goLeft();
    } else if (redBubble.direction === 'down') {
        redBubble.goDown();
    }
};

class Bubble {
    constructor(x, y, d) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.d = d;
        this.direction = 'right';
    }
    show() {
        fill(255);
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.d * 2);
    }
    goRight() {
        this.x = this.x + 1;
        if (this.x === 350) {
            this.direction = 'up';
        }
    }
    goLeft() {
        this.x = this.x - 1;
        if (this.x === 30) {
            this.direction = 'down';
        }
    }
    goUp() {
        this.y = this.y - 1;
        if (this.y === 30) {
            this.direction = 'left';
        }
    }
    goDown() {
        this.y = this.y + 1;
        if (this.y === 300) {
            this.direction = 'right';
        }
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/p5@0.6.1/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this great explanation! Really appreciate it.